# Downward compatibility of webrtc renegotiation

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc

I'm wondering how to implement screen sharing (or any other task in which a track is added to a peer connection after the initial offer/answer was completed). I see 2 possibilites:

1. In "modern webrtc" this seems to be done via pc.onnegotiationneeded and a possible rollback if both peers try to do an offer at the same time (see https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#perfect-negotiation-example). But rollback is only recently supported properly in chrome and firefox and not at all in other browsers and it does also not seem to be covered by adapter.js.
2. I guess the old way would be that one peer always does the offer (the "offer-peer") and if the other peer adds a track later, it would need to ask the offer-peer (e.g. via signaling) to send a new offer (to prevent races). This seems overly complicated and also adds latency if the offer needs to be "requested" via signaling.

So my question is: Is there either a third option that I missed or can I somehow make possibility 1) downwards compatible?

**P.S.** I know that you can use replaceTrack and do not need to renegotiate, but this only works if you already had a video track before that you can replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called signaling glare. Perfect negotiation attempts to avoid it but as you say, it is not implemented everywhere and is not polyfillable.
The third alternative would be that the side creating a new offer does *not* immediately set it as local description but waits until either
1/ receiving an answer
2/ receiving a conflicting offer in which case the glare handling (typically a number as tie breaker) determines whether that offer has a higher precedence.